# LatLng Bounds To Show Custom Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the code below to show markers within a given location from a mySQL database. I'm trying to set the LatLng bounds so I can see all the markers for each given location but it's not working, i.e. the map does not show all the markers within the viewable map, and I also receive a error saying that the 'findid is undefined'. Being a little new to this I'm not sure whether it's the code or the positioning of this piece of code that is wrong.

I just wondered whether it would be at all possible please that someone could take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            Artefact: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Coin: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Jewellery: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:14, 
            mapTypeId: 'satellite' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var findid = markers[i].getAttribute("findid");
            var locationid = markers[i].getAttribute("locationid"); 
            var dateoftrip = markers[i].getAttribute("dateoftrip");
            var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory");
            var findname = markers[i].getAttribute("findname");
            var finddescription = markers[i].getAttribute("finddescription");
            var detectorname = markers[i].getAttribute("detectorname");
            var searchheadname = markers[i].getAttribute("searchheadname");
            var detectorsettings = markers[i].getAttribute("detectorsettings");
            var pasref = markers[i].getAttribute("pasref");
            var findimage= markers[i].getAttribute("findimage");
            var additionalcomments= markers[i].getAttribute("additionalcomments");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon")));
            var icon = customIcons[findcategory] || {}; 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: 'Click to view details',
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 

            } 
            }); 
            } 

            // Creating a LatLngBounds object
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            // Looping through the places array
            for (var i = 0; i < findid.length; i += 1) {
            // Extending the bounds object with each LatLng
            bounds.extend(findid[i]);
            }
            // Adjusting the map to new bounding box
            map.fitBounds(bounds)

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            </head> 

            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            Artefact: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Coin: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            Jewellery: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            var markers;

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:14, 
            mapTypeId: 'satellite' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var findid = markers[i].getAttribute("findid");
            var locationid = markers[i].getAttribute("locationid"); 
            var dateoftrip = markers[i].getAttribute("dateoftrip");
            var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory");
            var findname = markers[i].getAttribute("findname");
            var finddescription = markers[i].getAttribute("finddescription");
            var detectorname = markers[i].getAttribute("detectorname");
            var searchheadname = markers[i].getAttribute("searchheadname");
            var detectorsettings = markers[i].getAttribute("detectorsettings");
            var pasref = markers[i].getAttribute("pasref");
            var findimage= markers[i].getAttribute("findimage");
            var additionalcomments= markers[i].getAttribute("additionalcomments");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon")));
            var icon = customIcons[findcategory] || {}; 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: 'Click to view details',
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 
            } 
            }); 
               // Creating a LatLngBounds object
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            // Looping through the places array
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i += 1) {
            // Extending the bounds object with each LatLng
            bounds.extend(markers[i]);
            }
            // Adjusting the map to new bounding box
            map.fitBounds(bounds)   
            } 
            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            </head> 

            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to loop through the `findid` array when it doesn't exist. There are 2 reasons for why it doens't exist:

1. It's not declared in the scope where you're trying to loop through it
2. Even if it was, it wouldn't be defined until *after* the ajax request, which you're using to get the XML data, has completed

The "A" in Ajax stands for "asynchronous", meaning that when you request something, your code continues immediately, and doesn't wait for the server to respond to the request.

As for the first point, the function you pass to `downloadUrl` loops through the `<marker>` elements in the XML and pulls out a lot of data into *local* variables, but it doesn't actually do anything with most of them. And since they're local, they don't exist after the function has finished. In fact, they just get overwritten for each `<marker>` element, but that's it.

So, rather than trying to loop through `findid` outside the function (where it doesn't exist), put the code from the loop into the function, so it can actually access the marker you create there.

**Edit**

Here's just the `load` function rewritten so it should work (you'll still need the rest of the code). I've removed all the local variables, because you don't use them for anything. In the end you're constructing a marker from the latitude/longitude - all the other data, you weren't using. If you need it for something, add it in later.

```
function load() { 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
        zoom:14, 
        mapTypeId: 'satellite' 
    });

    var bounds  = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var markers = [];

    downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
        var xml = data.responseXML; 
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        // loop through the markers in the xml file
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat")), 
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon"))
            );
            var icon = customIcons[findcategory] || {}; 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
                map: map, 
                position: point,
                title: 'Click to view details',
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });
            // LatLngBounds expects a LatLng object - not a marker object
            bounds.extend(point);
        }
        // fit the map after all the points and markers have been created - i.e. after the loop
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. I know that this is down to my lack of knowledge, but I've made the changes that I think you were suggesting but I'm now getting the error 'markers.length is null or not an object'. I've posted my reworked code in my original post. Could you perhaps take a look at this and let me know what I need to change. I appreciate that to the more seasoned programmer it may be quite clear, but I am fairly new to this, so please bear with me. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: Hi, just wanted to post an update to say that I've resolved the issue. Many thanks for your time and trouble. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: @IRHM: I've updated my answer with some code. I'm not going to write all of it for you, but hopefully it'll make more sense now. Also: Indent your code! It's very difficult to figure out what belongs where, when things aren't properly indented

Comment: @IRHM: Darn, I was interrupted by a phone call when posting and didn't see your comment until after I'd posted

Comment: Hi, no problem at all. Sincere thanks for helping me out. I completely understand about some of the issues around the formatting of my coding etc. Being new to this I'm learning as I go on. kind regards. Chris